# How do I find out if a computer is OEM licensed or if any?

Tags: windows, license

Are there tools to find out if there is an OEM key embedded in my computer's Bios/EFI ?

**This question requires some backstory. If you are interested in the backstory, or why am I asking this question, please continue to read, otherwise Ignore**

[The full backstory and my thoughts](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aria-dev/d767d1e9701208e1a0d604ae45e79fec/raw/a7b73da2962ad2cf42e0b0c9e39a6b1bf0555b65/Backstory.txt)

Comment: If the 'agent' did not apply Microsoft's labels to the PCs, then they're not OEM-licensed. That's what Microsoft and the Business Software Alliance https://bsa.org would say if they visit. Only the 'agent' could prove otherwise. See https://www.google.com/search?q=business+software+alliance+enforcement for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *SLMGR* to get some information.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `cmd` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
- At the Command prompt type `SLMGR /DLV` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

A dialog similar to the following should display license information:

[image: SLMGR dialog]

See [3 ways to check whether your Windows is activated and genuine](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-learn-copy-windows-7-windows-8-activated) for more details, and [TechJourney](https://techjourney.net/slmgr-commands-and-options-for-windows-product-key-kms-token-ad-activation/) for more on *SLMGR*.

[The Windows key can also be found in BIOS/UEFI](https://www.intowindows.com/recover-windows-product-key-bios-efi/). The tool can be downloadewd from [Neosmart](https://neosmart.net/Download/Register) (registration is not required, just click <kbd>dowload</kbd>).

Comment: The current windows installations are not licensed/pirated. I need to find out if there was any genuine OEM key for any previous versions of Windows on the BIOS

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt as administrator, then type "slmgr -dli" and press Enter key to check.
I searched for 2 captures which contains retail and OEM. Please see below.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I know that the current windows 10 installations are not licensed/pirated. Wanted to know if computers came with windows installed from the manufacturer.

Comment: As you are using Windows 10 as the OS, Windows 10 will activate itself if it was activate on this device before. So if it is a new device with OEM key installed in BIOS, we could connect to network and let it activate auto. If it is an old device and connectting with internet but keeps invaild , it might have not retail key or OEM key, because Windows activation server will recorded the hardware GUID when it first activate, and when PC connect internet again, it would activate auto. If it is an old device, and changed hardware before, we need to activate again through Microsoft support.

Comment: You could check the link below, to check if it is available to find OEM key installed in BIOS.https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-retrieve-windows-8-oem-product-key-from-bios  But according to your descirption, it seems that all those computers all installed with no vaild product key, even without product key. You could upload the information after run "SLMGR /DLV"